# Cast exception with FieldPosition in XFAFlattener

Tags: java, itext, xfa

Trying to do a proof of concept using a trial version of XFA Worker. When I attempt to convert a XFA document I constructed, I get a java.lang.ClassCastException: com.itextpdf.tool.xml.xtra.xfa.positioner.FieldPositioner cannot be cast to java.lang.String error occuring when the com.itextpdf.tool.xml.xtra.xfa.XFAFlattener.flatten method is called? Any ideas on what the issue(s) might be would be helpful.

Comment: Can you post your code and details about the exception you're getting?

Comment: At least post a stack trace and your XFAWorker version.

Comment: Well, actually we would need the XFA form that causes the problem (because the source code to flatten an XFA form is pretty straightforward; there's very little that can go wrong with it). If you could provide a link to the XFA form, I'll forward it to the XFA team at iText (they are not on StackOverflow).

Comment: I got same issue on 5.5.3 , stack trace is java.lang.ClassCastException: com.itextpdf.tool.xml.xtra.xfa.positioner.FieldPositioner cannot be cast to java.lang.String
 at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.xtra.xfa.js.JsTree.addChild(JsTree.java:94)
 at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.xtra.xfa.js.JsNode.addChild(JsNode.java:225)
 at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.xtra.xfa.positioner.Positioner.addChild(Positioner.java:538)
 at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.xtra.xfa.pipe.FormBuilder.buildSubformInstance(FormBuilder.java:339)